# When tap an UIButton of a subview, then I can't tap another button of that subview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an iPhone app, and when I tap a button, I add a subview (UIView) that have 3 buttons.

One is for public at Facebook, another is to tweet, and the last one is to hide the subview.

My problem is that when I've tap on facebook or tweet button and complete the post, then I can't tap other button.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: show me the money ... I mean code :)

Comment: If the screen is freezing, it means your blocking the main thread. Use GCD and dispatch the posting to FB and tweet work on a background thread.. and @SamBudda is right..throw some code if you want help

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an action sheet instead?

Here is the code:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Share" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook",@"Twitter", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you decide to use an action sheet?